# Seeking shapefile of Cumbria (county) outline?

Tags: uk

Looking for a shapefile of the entire county of Cumbria (UK) to use in ArcMap.

Any ideas on where I can find one?

Comment: I think questions seeking data, even when it is spatial data, are usually better researched, and if necessary, are asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: http://www.gadm.org will give you shapefile of every county in the UK, as long as you're in non-commercial purposes domain. From that you can filter.

Answer (score 5):

Ordnance Survey as the national mapping agency of the UK should always be your first stop for this sort of data. You need the [BoundaryLine](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundary-line.html) dataset which contains modern and historical county boundaries. It is available as a free download from the the [OpenData section](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html).